# How can I start to build voice chat application iPhone?

Tags: iphone, chat, sip, voip, voice

I want to build voice chat application for iphone.

After surfing and searching i conclude that for making of voice chat app i have to use VOIP/SIP protocol.

So my question is that,

1. It's necessary to use VOIP/SIP protocol for voice chat? If YES then how can i use VOIP/SIP in my app? Is there any tutorial or blog which explain step by step implementation?
2. And if it's not necessary to use VOIP/SIP then what is the alternate way for developing Chat application ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to use SIP. SIP is one of the umbrella standards that enable you to create multimedia sessions of any kind, however with SIP you will also have to implement a number of other things - Offer/Answer model using SDP (Session Description Protocol), use a RTP (Real time protocol) for actual voice transmission, likely MSRP (Message Session Relay Protocol) for session oriented messaging and then possibly look at Presence and whole slew of standards under SIP/SIMPLE.

Now you don't have to do it all and it all depends on what you want to do and how many and what types of other clients and 3rd party servers you want to interface with. 
Have a look at [existing free SIP software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_software) and see what makes sense for you.

Alternatively have a look at XMPP which is more suited for chat and presence kind of requirements. Specifically look at [Jabber](http://www.jabber.org/) and see if that makes sense.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer... i understand but how can i use this protocol's(SDP,RTP,MSRP,SIP) in iPhone app? can you provide me some example or tutorial which can teach voice chat implementation in iOS app???

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use SIP. For example, ConnectyCube video solution is based on XMPP for chat and signaling to establish the connection before the call and WebRTC standard for video calls. You can check [code samples](https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/code-samples) to see how they implemented it on iOS.

To try the solution you can register a free account. If it suits you, you can use their SDK to speed up the development.
The benefit of using a ready backend with SDK is also that you do not need to worry about setting up a STUN/TURN server for routing video calls. They have a shared one you can use.

Comment: you might want to disclose your affiliation in your posts.